# Eclipse Android - how can I see what methods are executed without using Log.d() everywhere

Tags: android, eclipse

In my android application whenever I need to trace the events chronology and variables' values in complicated classes and sequences, I place Log.d() everywhere but it is cumbersome and wasteful.

Is there a plugin or a way that I can follow the sequence of methods execution and the values of all the variables without having to put so many Log.d calls?

Comment: use debugger or use sysytem.out.prinln or use toast messages or use alert boxes whatever you want you can use even log.d is the best option

Comment: I dont want to have to write out these calls in each method. I want something that automatically tells me every method and every variable used

Comment: use a debugger and set a breakpoint at the beginning of the methods

Comment: at the beginning of each method? and what is a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Starting method profiling

Method profiling is a means to track certain metrics about a method, such as number of calls, execution time, and time spent executing the method. If you want more granular control over where profiling data is collected, use the startMethodTracing() and stopMethodTracing() methods. For more information about generating trace logs, see Profiling and Debugging UIs.

Before you start method profiling in DDMS, be aware of the following restrictions:

Android 2.1 and earlier devices must have an SD card present and your application must have permission to write to the SD card.
Android 2.2 and later devices do not need an SD card. The trace log files are streamed directly to your development machine.
To start method profiling:

On the Devices tab, select the process that you want to enable method profiling for.
Click the Start Method Profiling button.
Interact with your application to start the methods that you want to profile.
Click the Stop Method Profiling button. DDMS stops profiling your application and opens Traceview with the method profiling information that was collected between the time you clicked on Start Method Profiling and Stop Method Profiling.

Please refer this: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Answer (score 0):

another option would be the simplifying the `Log` call by using your own method:

```
    public static void doLog(String msg){
    StackTraceElement[] mStackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    Log.d(mStackTrace[3].getMethodName(), msg);
   }
```

The docs:

> The last element of the array represents the bottom of the stack,
>   which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.

since `doLog()` is also a method, you would need the index 3 to display the name of the method the log was actually called from. This way you'd only need to call

```
MyHelperClass.doLog("Test");
```

This is the approach I often use for debugging. And yes, this is the easiest and best way when using built-in logging system.